# Finger print authentication app for unlock door lock (IOT project)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, node.js, iot

I'm trying to create IOT project with raspberry pi for unlock door with finger print sensor on smart phone.

I want write node JS sever on raspberry pi and simple UI for show  who, when unlock door or trying to unlock it and this system alert admin when some one trying to unlock door.

For example my phone and raspberry pi connect to local host network. I use my phone app to unlock door and this action record in server and we can see it from simple UI app.

I'm electrical engineer and I familiar with java Script and python but I don't know how create smart phone app (iOS/Android) for authentication finger print and send it to server.

I need help how create this phone app.

I know this is general question **just hint me what should I do.**

Thank you.

Comment: On iOS (and on Android too I suspect) you can't get the fingerprint data. You can simply ask the device to prompt the user for a fingerprint authentication. Your app then gets a yes/no result.

Comment: [saharsojoodi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15230377/saharsojoodi) suggests reading  http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Fingerprint_Authentication_Tutorial